# What does this onclick (onclick="this.name='abc'") mean?

Tags: javascript, onclick

What does this code do? What is the $this referencing in this case?

```
<button type="submit" onclick="this.name='abc'" title="update wishlist" class="button btn-update"><span><span>update wishlist</span></span></button>
```

What is the *onclick="this.name='abc'"* doing? What happens when the button is clicked? Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It will add name(that is an attribute) value 'abc' to attribute 'name' at click event. this mean reference to current control.  In your case its referring to input control so it will add attribute 'name' with value 'abc'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anonymous function in an intrinsic event handler is called in the context of the element on which it is set.

So `this` is the `<button>`

Comment: So this is just giving the name  "abc" to the input? Its the same as writing name = 'abc'?

Comment: @Quentin: isn't it `<button>`?

Comment: @EOB — No, it doesn't happen until the button is clicked.